# I can't seem to figure out how to fix two lints in my javascript. Can someone help me understand?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, lint

I just started javascript and made my first game today! I am very happy with it and in the process of making it lint free.

I'm getting really frustrated, i fixed almost all my mistakes(lints) but there are two I can't seem to fix! I've been trying for over an hour. Could someone please help me solve this? I'm getting frustrated :(

The lints are:

5   'prompt' was used before it was defined.    var name = prompt("Hallo Speler, wat is uw naam?.", "naam van speler");

5   Expected an identifier and instead saw '"'. var name = prompt("Hallo Speler, wat is uw naam?.", "naam van speler");

This is my javascript code:

```js
//Schrijft functie begin spel. value van de input wordt een string. Opnieuw knop wordt disabled.



var name = prompt("Hallo Speler, wat is uw naam?.", "naam van speler");

var data = [
        [0, 11, "Een hele goede morgen,"],
        [12, 17, "Goede middag,"],
        [18, 24, "Goede avond"]
    ],
    hr = new Date().getHours();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (hr >= data[i][0] && hr <= data[i][1]) {
        document.getElementById('welkom').innerHTML = data[i][2] + " " + name;
    }
}


function beginspel() {



    document.getElementById("input_txt").value = "";

    document.getElementById("input_txt").focus();

    document.getElementById("input_txt").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("guess_btn").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("playAgain_btn").disabled = true;

    //Tekst weergeeft op het begin informatie over wat je moet doen.
    document.getElementById("message_txt").innerHTML = "Kies een nummer tussen 1 en 100.";

    //nummer van de computer wordt berekend.
     randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);

    //variabele input is de tekst van input_txt
    input = document.getElementById("input_txt");


    var clicks = 0; // sets a global variable
    // when the window loads

    document.getElementById("guess_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        //The above creates an event listener to tell the
        //script what to do when someone clicks on an element
        //with the id "button"

        clicks++; // adds 1 to variable clicks
        document.getElementById('aantalKlik').innerHTML = "U heeft " + clicks + " keer geraden!"; // displays clicks popup
    })



}



var guess_btn = document.getElementById('guess_btn');
guess_btn.addEventListener('click', guessNumber);

var playAgain_btn = document.getElementById('playAgain_btn');
playAgain_btn.addEventListener('click', beginspel);




function guessNumber() {
   guess = document.getElementById("input_txt").value;

    document.getElementById("input_txt").focus();




    if (guess === "") {
        document.getElementById("message_txt").innerHTML = "0 is te laag. Probeer opnieuw!";
    } else if (guess > randomNumber) {
        document.getElementById("message_txt").innerHTML = guess + " is te hoog. Probeer opnieuw!";
        input_txt.value = "";
    } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
        document.getElementById("message_txt").innerHTML = guess + " is te laag. Probeer opnieuw!"
        input_txt.value = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message_txt").innerHTML = "Je hebt goed geraden! Het nummer is " + guess + ".";
        input_txt.value = "";




        endGame();
    }


}

function endGame() {
    document.getElementById("input_txt").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("guess_btn").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("playAgain_btn").disabled = false;
}

window.onload = beginspel;
```

Thanks a lot for taking the time helping me.

xx

Comment: `window.promp()` for that first error, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because it does not know where `prompt` is defined. You can prefix it with `window` like this: `window.prompt(...`

Or you could add `prompt` to the list of "globals" passed in the jshint configuration: http://jshint.com/docs/